# np.random.shuffle not working(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
np.random.shuffle([1,2,3,4])
```

Why do I get [1,2,3,4] as the o/p? Shouldn't it be shuffled?

Comment: None of this produces *any* output.

Comment: Please read [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html). The function modify a sequence **in-place** by shuffling its contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `numpy.random.shuffle` function modifies its argument in place. It doesn't `return` anything.

So you need to create a variable to hold the list you're going to shuffle, and check it after shuffling to see there result:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
np.random.shuffle(a)
print(a)
```